# Change the value of the query

Tags: c#, datatable

i have query
i need change value, if value = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" then **new value** row = "no time", how?

```
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
source.DataSource = dt;
```

so i use

```
source[2] = (source[2] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") ? "no time" : source[2];
```

but it`s wrong, i think need to use **while?**

Comment: How do you arrive at `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the query (maybe you can add something there )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is betting to change the query of data source but if you do not have access over that for instance you get data from some third party web service, Assuming you do not want to change the why you get data from data source (Web service / Database) You can change in data table in C# code and assign to data source of your GUI control.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     if (dr[2] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
         dr[2] = "No time"; // Use column name instead if possible dr["yourcolumnname"]
}

source.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

Comment: You need to get the value no time from your control and convert it back to default date or null what ever suits you for inserting in MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

change to if statement:

```
if (source[2] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") source[2] = "no time.";
```